# Hamilonian as a sum of quantum oscillators with symmetric matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, coupled-oscillators

I'm watching the Introduction to Quantum Field Theory course by Tobias Osborne (the lecture notes for which can be found here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/avstjohn/qft/master/QFT.pdf). In the lecture, the total energy of a system Hamiltonian is described as:
$$H=\sum_{j=1}^n{ \frac{p_{j}^2}{2m}}+\frac{m}{2}\sum_{j,k=1}^nq_{j}[Q]_{jk}q_{k}$$
where $Q$ is $n \times n$ symmetric matrix. Can someone explain why would this be the case? To me this Hamiltonian seems describing a system of harmonic oscillators. Also why does $Q$ need to be a symmetric matrix?

Comment: Hint: How much would an antisymmetric $Q$ matrix contribute to the potential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can decompose any square matrix into a symmetric matrix plus an antisymmetric matrix.

Proof:

Define $S=\frac{1}{2}\left(Q+Q^T\right)$, where $Q^T$ is the transpose of $Q$. $S$ is a symmetric matrix. Also define $A=\frac{1}{2}\left(Q-Q^T\right)$. $A$ is an antisymmetric matrix.

Then the decomposition of $Q$ is simply

\begin{equation}
Q=S+A
\end{equation}
which one can verify easily plugging in the definitions of $S$ and $A$.

2. The antisymmetric part of $Q$ does not contribute to the quadratic coupling term.

Proof:

First break the coupling term into $A$ and $S$:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{ij} q_i Q_{ij} q_j = \sum_{ij} q_i S_{ij} q_j + \sum_{ij} q_i A_{ij} q_j
\end{equation}

Then use the property, $A_{ij}=-A_{ji}$ (since $A$ is an antisymmetric matrix). The second term above becomes

\begin{equation}
\sum_{ij} q_i A_{ij} q_j = - \sum_{ij} q_i A_{ji} q_j
\end{equation}

Next, we can *swap* the the indices $i\leftrightarrow j$ in the summand. This is simply relabelling the indices of each term. (We don't need to worry about the $ij$ indices under the $\sum$ sign since $\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N(...)=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^N(...)$)

\begin{equation}
-\sum_{ij} q_i A_{ji} q_j = -\sum_{ij} q_j A_{ij} q_i
\end{equation}

Finally, we can swap $q_i$ and $q_j$ above, since multiplication is commutative.

\begin{equation}
-\sum_{ij} q_j A_{ij} q_i = -\sum_{ij} q_i A_{ij} q_j
\end{equation}

Putting the above steps together, we have shown that

\begin{equation}
\sum_{ij} q_i A_{ij} q_j = -\sum_{ij} q_i A_{ij} q_j
\end{equation}

In other words, the sum is equal to minus itself, $\Sigma=-\Sigma$. This is only consistent if the sum itself is zero, which is what we wanted to show. QED.

It can also help to work out a small example explicitly -- the reason this works is that every term like $q_1 A_{12} q_2$ will cancel with a corresponding term like $q_2 A_{21} q_1$, due to the antisymmetry of $A$.

By a similar train of thought, you can show that the symmetric part $S$ gives a non-zero contribution in general.

3. By 1 and 2 above, we can consider $Q$ to be a symmetric matrix without any loss of generality. Or, equivalently, if you prefer, if $Q$ is not already a symmetric matrix, you can define $\tilde{Q}=Q-\frac{1}{2}(Q-Q^T)$ which **is** symmetric and use $\tilde{Q}$ instead. We have shown in 2 above that $Q$ and $\tilde{Q}$ will lead to the same dynamics, since the difference is an antisymmetric matrix, which does not contribute to the coupling between the $q_i$.